# Does Mysql Select Query can fetch 500,000 record?

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL SELECT query for fetching records. If i have 500,000 of user's record in my users table. does SELECT query support?

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to select 500,000 records at once in the first place?

Comment: For send the email newsletter to all users. who are all registered in the site based on the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. even you can get more then 500000 rows. There is no such limit by mysql.

But you should control no of records by programming language using pagination and using `limit` clause with select. Fetching such large no of records at once will degrade performance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Running a `SELECT` over 500k records is doable.